# String vazia passada para getElementById()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou usando o `jQuery` e tenho o seguinte código

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

      $(".checkParcelamento").click(function(){
          var bandeira = $("#bandeiraCartao").val();
          var numero_cartao = $("input[name='numero_cartao']").val();
          var cvv = $("input[name='cvv']").val();
          var mes_cartao = $("input[name='mes_cartao']").val();
          var ano_cartao = $("input[name='ano_cartao']").val();

          if(numero_cartao == ''){

            swal('Erro!', 'Por favor, informe o número do seu cartão para continuar', 'error');

          }else if(cvv == ''){

            swal('Erro!', 'Por favor, informe o código de segurança para continuar', 'error');

          }else if(mes_cartao == ''){

            swal('Erro!', 'Por favor, informe o mês da validade para continuar', 'error');

          }else if(ano_cartao == ''){

            swal('Erro!', 'Por favor, informe o ano da validade para continuar', 'error');

          }else{


            $gn.ready(function(checkout) {

            var callback = function(error, response) {
              if(error) {
                // Trata o erro ocorrido
                console.error(error);
              } else {

                checkout.getInstallments(50000,bandeira, function(error2, response2){
                  if(error2) {
                    // Trata o erro ocorrido
                    console.log(error2);
                  } else {

                    console.log(response2);

                    $.each(response2, function(i,e){

                    $.each(e, function(a,b){

                      if(a == 'installments'){

                        var html = '<select name="parcelamento" class="form-control">';

                        $.each(b, function(c,d){

                          html += '<option value="'+d.currency+'">'+d.installment+'x de '+d.currency+'</option>';

                        });

                        html += '</select>';

                        $("#parcelamento").html(html);

                      }
                    });
                  });
                  }
                });
                // Trata a resposta
                console.log(response);
              }
            };

            checkout.getPaymentToken({
              brand: bandeira, // bandeira do cartão
              number: numero_cartao, // número do cartão
              cvv: cvv, // código de segurança
              expiration_month: mes_cartao, // mês de vencimento
              expiration_year: ano_cartao // ano de vencimento
            }, callback);

          });


          }
      });
    });
```

O problema ocorre na linha **$(".checkParcelamento").click(function(){**.
Ao clicar no botão, ao invés de executar o código, ele me retorna o erro `String vazia passada para getElementById()` que da no arquivo do jQuery.

O Estranho é que tenho outros códigos que faz o `click` normalmente, mas nesse não está dando. O código do botão:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="button" id="checkParcelamento" class="btn btn-primary checkParcelamento" value="Continuar">
</div>
```

Já tentei usar com **#** mas o mesmo erro ocorre.

Comment: Penso que o problema esteja sendo causado por alguma coisa externa do seu código. Veja como roda no fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hamurabiaraujo/00Ljx85j/2/

Comment: Por que você precisa do jQuery(document).ready no inicio se você monitora é o click?

Comment: -1
votar contra
 

O correto é utilizar o # para pegar por ID com o "."(ponto) você esta pedindo para ele monitorar a classe.

Recomendo voltar para o # e ir colocando alert pelo código para ver o que ele está recebendo, ou ir acompanhando pelo console do navegar com BreakPoints

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho Eu tenho alguns códigos assim, mas porque preciso me garantir que o objeto com o qual vou trabalhar está carregado. Pode ser uma lista grande ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o jQuery possa ter uma depedência com alguns outros recursos do navegador quando ele vai interpretar a query do primeiro parâmetro de `$(query)` -> `jQuery(query)` -> `$.fn.find(query)`, etc., por exemplo, talvez o jQuery precisa descobrir se a query forma elementos HTML, por exemplo:

```
$("<span></span>")
```

O Mozilla Firefox pode ter um método nativo que funciona diferente dos outros navegadores, talvez o jQuery depende desse método nativo, daí ocorre alguma confusão e o jQuery acaba passando uma string vázia para `document.getElementById`. Outra possibilidade de excepção pode ser (muito e muito)raramente causada por uma extensão do navegador.

Observação: esse erro `Empty string passed to getElementById()` existe apenas no Firefox, os outros navegadores são menos *"explicitos"* e retornam `null` ou um elemento HTML (não estou afirmando, talvez possa existir um navegador semelhante ao Firefox).

**Uma tentativa para resolver o problema**

Se o jQuery souber que a query é um objeto, talvez ele não precise interpretá-la:

```
$(document.getElementById("checkParcelamento"));
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro está sendo gerado em alguma extensão do Firefox, e não em seu código.

PS: Também utilizo a **API de Checkout da Gerencianet** e seu código esta correto (pagamento c/ cartão).

Você tem liberdade para utilizar tanto **id (#)** quando **classe (.)** no seletor jQuery, funciona da mesma forma, lembrando que para ID você pode ter quantos seletores desejar mas somente um elemento com esse ID na página, já por classe você pode ter quantos seletores e elementos desejar, sendo mais vantajoso utilizar classe porque você pode ter mais de um acionador do evento  na mesma página sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Srs. de fato o problema está provavelmente fora do código apresentado conforme já relatado [nesse post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462974/how-to-remove-empty-string-passed-to-getelementbyid-warning-with-jquery-mobi), falta de atributo no `label`

Quando falta id no label

```
<label for="">Stuff:</label>
```

corrigido

```
<label for="someID">Stuff:</label>
```